# What is the min & max allowed values for xsd:dateTime and xsd:time types?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I have XML which contains a `DateTime` element and a `Time` element, both of which expect a XSD `dateTime` and `time` value respectively, in optional attributes `min` and `max`.

So imagine something like this:

```
<DateTime min="..." max="..." ... />
<Time min="..." max="..." ... />
```

I'm writing corresponding XSD and want to specify the default values for the min & max attributes of these elements (since they're both optional), and ideally I'd like to make them the min & max permitted values according to the XSD spec.

I see XSD is gleaning most of the content for these types from ISO 8601, but I can't find a complete min & max permitted value for each type.

What is the min and max supported values for the XSD dateTime and time types?

Comment: Some systems use 1st Jan 1970 as their epoch start. Some use 1st Jan 1900. Some use the start of the Gregorian calendar (somewhen in the 1500s). You should set the min/max according to the requirements of your project.

Comment: @kimbert My project compares these dates/times to other dates/times provided in the XML; it doesn't have any pre-set min & max.  That's why I'd like to set the defaults to the lowest and highest value allowed by XSD.

Comment: My answer stands - there are realistic limits to the values that you expect to receive. All projects have to make this type of judgement from time to time. Why not set the min to the start of the Gregorian calendar and the max to 3000AD?

Comment: @kimbert Thanks, but your suggestion does not answer my question.  My app has no pretense of expected range of dates and it makes no sense to add an artificial restriction.  My app only requires DateTime/Time values to conform to ISO 8601 format; the specific values are the user's choice.  I only want to restrict the values to those supported by XSD.

Comment: Neither XSD not ISO8601 say anything about min/max values for dates and times. Any limits will be implementation-specific. I think you should allow the user to specify these min/max values in some other way. You could allow them to restrict your basic date/time types via a defined extension mechanism in your XSD.